# js width equal parent height

Tags: javascript, equals

I have a common menu with structure `nav > ul > li > a`

If li has child dropdown menu I create dropdown toggle

```js
var dropdownToggle = $('<button />', {
  'class': 'dropdown-toggle',
  'aria-expanded': false
});

container.find('.menu-item-has-children > a').after(dropdownToggle);

var parentSize = dropdownToggle.parent().height();
dropdownToggle.height(parentSize);
dropdownToggle.width(parentSize);
```

```css
.dropdown-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

I want the height and width `.dropdown-toggle` to be equal height parent (li), but it's not working

Where is a problem?

`console.log(parentSize)` print 42.2 - ok, this height

I know that there is a solution with CSS `padding-top: 100%`, but I want to use JS

Comment: you are setting `top:0` to your button, change its top to parent's height like `dropdownToggle.css("top",parentSize)`

Answer (score 0):

use  jquery as follows

```js
$('.dropdown-togggle').css({
'width':$(this).parent().width()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and in html add the class dropdowntoggle to whatever element you want to apply it's parent's width.

Comment: Here it worked

$('.dropdown-toggle').css({ 
'height': parentSize, 
'width': parentSize, 
})